# Kibana Fleet server is offline

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm, fleet

I am new to Kibana. Yesterday I setup a fleet server local on my machine and it working. To day I open it up then I see it is offline, last checked 23h ago. Any one can help ? I face this situation 2 times, first is on my windows, then this time I install it on Window Linux Subsystem and get the same issue

I first install kibana, elasticsearch and fleet server on window. Then I got the issue. This time I tried on Window Linux Subsystem I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

The reason is I did not run the elastic agent. I go to the installed folder and run it. The fleet status go back to healthy